# Best practice for creating Nuget packages

Tags: sdk, nuget, package

We are looking to make our product SDK available via NuGet packages. The product consists of multiple assemblies, some of which are dependent on each other.
The question we are trying to answer is how many NuGet packages should we create? One per assembly? One per the entire product? Is there a general rule of thumb or best practice we should follow?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NuGet packages generally should be one per assembly. From [NuGet FAQ](https://docs.nuget.org/consume/nuget-faq)

> NuGet.org allows uploading packages up to 250MB. As a best practice,
>   we recommend uploading smaller packages that are < 1 MB and using
>   dependencies to link together packages. As a rule of thumb, packages
>   contain only one assembly to avoid collissions.
>
> ......
>
> Dependencies are mostly static and never change. When fixing a bug in code, the dependencies may not have to be updated. If your
>   dependencies ship in the same package you end up reshipping the large
>   packages every time. By splitting NuGet packages into smaller chunks
>   (dependencies), upgrades are much more fine-grained for the end user
>   of the NuGet package.